# DROP and TRUNCATE table on MySQL 8.0.35 freezes the DB

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

We recently upgraded from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0.35 in AWS RDS.

There is a log table that services write to and we rotate it daily, using `RENAME TABLE` command.

Later when we perform a `DROP` or `TRUNCATE` on this table (~10-15 GB size) the DB freezes for 5-6 minutes.

During those minutes

- DB does not report any metrics
- Clients get timeouts and disconnect
- OS metrics show significant drop in IO and CPU

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `test_test_test` (
  `rowId` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ruId` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `sessionId` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `transSource` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dcsnType` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dcsnTypeManual` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dcsnReason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dcsnPlcRsn` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstDcnRule` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payload` text,
  `insertTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

### OS Metrics

Notice the DB metrics (bottom 3 graphs) are extrapolated (no measurements) during 07:33-07:41
[image]

The table is not used by any services when we run `DROP` or `TRUNCATE`

Would appreciate any theories, explanations or directions to explore.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312404/mysql-rds-drop-formerly-huge-table-without-freezing-db

Comment: What OS?   (Some OSs take a long time to free up space.)

Comment: My guess is that if you analyzed data content of each column used, you would find you have OVERPROVISIONED every column.  There is NO PRIMARY Key, may not be required but could have a favorable impact, even if it just INT with AutoIncrement.  If you do choose to have an index, processing would be significantly faster when you have a PRIMARY key. For assistance, view my profile and get in touch.

Comment: Would like to see TEXT results of this QUERY at 7:34 and 7:39 and 7:44 if that could be arranged. SELECT 'SLEEPING time use', 
COUNT(*),SUM(time)  
FROM information_schema.processlist 
WHERE 
command="Sleep";

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of SHOW EXTENDED INDEX FROM schema.test_test_text; and SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "test_test_test";  when table is loaded with data?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this huge table?  It has no visible indexes.  If you are simply recording data in case you need to replay it, I recommend you save it on the client side in its raw format.  That might let you spend less money on AWS and possibly improve performance when you need to replay.